# Android Multidex support library is disabled

Tags: android, android-multidex

I'm experiencing some problem with multidex support in my app, in fact the app install normally, but through the process, some activities crashed and the app, relaunches the main activity. In logcat I found this :

```
I/MultiDex: install
I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
```

But I followed recommendations to enable Multidex support :

Gradle :

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com..company.package"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 21
    versionName "2.1.3"

}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//compile project(':rangebar')
compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.3@aar') { transitive = true }
compile('com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
compile files('libs/itextpdf-5.5.9.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
...
```

Application class extends Multidex :

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
}
```

I don't know what I am exactly missing to get rid of this matter

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you either use multidex install in on attachBaseContext method or extend MultidexApplication using both are pointless as both do the same

Comment: @M.Ashish yes thank you, it did the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I/MultiDex: install I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex
>   support library is disabled.

You should set

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
```

**Manifest**

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
   ....>
```

Then **Clean-Rebuild-Run** .

Comment: Yes, and it was also M.Ashish's answer

Comment: @Houssem Conflict arising from `extends  MultiDexApplication `

Comment: but the first time this prob. rised I did not extended my class to MultidexApplication, for now the problem is solved, but the message "VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled." is still displaying

Comment: Why would you think everyone has a class that extends **Application**?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky review https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Answer (score 1):

But also to add to the answer on top^

In the Android Documentation it says, if you have minSdkVersion is 21 or higher, you do not need the multidex support library. So, I see why you did that there https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-on-l

The options you have are the below: 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle

**Don't forget to Add in your build.gradle(app)**

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
   }
    ...
}
```

**Option 1)** If you do not override the Application class, edit your manifest file to set android:name in the  tag as follows:
**This will be your entry: android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication**

```
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                    android:name=".MainActivity"
                    android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Option 2)** If you do override the Application class, change it to extend MultiDexApplication (if possible) as follows:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
```

**Option 3)** Or if you do override the Application class but it's not possible to change the base class, then you can instead override the attachBaseContext() method and call MultiDex.install(this) to enable multidex: **You add the code below without extending *MultiDexApplication***

```
public class MyApplication extends **SomeOtherApplication** {

  //You add the code below without extending **MultiDexApplication**
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```

**Caution:** Do not execute MultiDex.install() or any other code through reflection or JNI before MultiDex.install() is complete. Multidex tracing will not follow those calls, causing ClassNotFoundException or verify errors due to a bad class partition between DEX files.