# Android app crash, finding cause in logcat

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm posting here for help locating the issue that is causing a React Native Android app to crash. The app uses React Native Navigation. I can't work out which error is causing the app to crash. It crashes as it starts to load its main screen.

I removed `MultiDex.install` since the first comment but still get a crash.

**UPDATE:** The issue was not a crash at all, but a mix up of some older C++ code which was quitting the app when the MainActivity was stopping. Thanks for all the tips.

Apologies for posting a long log output!

```
2018-12-04 10:06:16.830 4603-4603/com.acme.myapp V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.acme.myapp/lib-main
2018-12-04 10:06:16.831 4603-4603/com.acme.myapp I/fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/com.acme.myapp/lib-main
2018-12-04 10:06:16.831 4603-4603/com.acme.myapp V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.acme.myapp/lib-main
2018-12-04 10:06:16.856 4603-4603/com.acme.myapp D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2018-12-04 10:06:16.889 4603-4603/com.acme.myapp D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
2018-12-04 10:06:16.889 4603-4603/com.acme.myapp D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
2018-12-04 10:06:16.893 4603-4603/com.acme.myapp D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.onJSBundleLoadedFromServer()
2018-12-04 10:06:16.895 4603-4603/com.acme.myapp D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
2018-12-04 10:06:16.896 4603-4603/com.acme.myapp D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
2018-12-04 10:06:16.926 1363-1872/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2018-12-04 10:06:16.931 4603-4685/com.acme.myapp D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
2018-12-04 10:06:17.883 1354-1354/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 4096
2018-12-04 10:06:17.898 1354-1354/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) allocator@2.0-s identical 1 line
2018-12-04 10:06:17.913 1354-1354/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 4096
2018-12-04 10:06:19.406 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp I/zygote: Thread[16,tid=4682,Native,Thread*=0xa09a4400,peer=0x131ec760,"Thread-2"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/com.acme.myapp-JUTtTZPIgePtTXCNsU1hrw==/lib/x86/libfb.so"
2018-12-04 10:06:19.410 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()
2018-12-04 10:06:19.414 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp D/SayItReactPackage: createViewManagers
2018-12-04 10:06:19.706 4603-4685/com.acme.myapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2018-12-04 10:06:19.706 4603-4685/com.acme.myapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2018-12-04 10:06:19.706 4603-4685/com.acme.myapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2018-12-04 10:06:19.706 4603-4685/com.acme.myapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2018-12-04 10:06:19.708 4603-4685/com.acme.myapp D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa3486a40: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2018-12-04 10:06:19.958 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp E/UCI4C: u_getDataDirectory()=/data/user/0/com.acme.myapp/files/icu
2018-12-04 10:06:19.991 4603-4685/com.acme.myapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3486a40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa34836a0)
2018-12-04 10:06:19.993 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.acme.myapp.RCTWordViewManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.009 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.273 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.horcrux.svg.RenderableViewManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.275 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.horcrux.svg.GroupShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.397 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.horcrux.svg.PathShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.399 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.horcrux.svg.CircleShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.400 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.horcrux.svg.EllipseShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.554 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.horcrux.svg.LineShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.559 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.horcrux.svg.RectShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.567 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.horcrux.svg.TextShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.574 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.horcrux.svg.TSpanShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.581 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.horcrux.svg.TextPathShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.587 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.horcrux.svg.ImageShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.594 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.horcrux.svg.ClipPathShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.597 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.horcrux.svg.DefsShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.597 4603-4685/com.acme.myapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3486a40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa34836a0)
2018-12-04 10:06:20.604 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.horcrux.svg.UseShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.609 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.horcrux.svg.SymbolShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.615 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.horcrux.svg.LinearGradientShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.621 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.horcrux.svg.RadialGradientShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.626 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.horcrux.svg.SvgViewManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.627 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.horcrux.svg.SvgViewShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.632 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.inprogress.reactnativeyoutube.YouTubeManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.638 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.BV.LinearGradient.LinearGradientManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.642 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTGroupViewManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.644 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTGroupShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.645 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTShapeViewManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.646 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTShapeShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.648 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTTextViewManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.649 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTTextShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.649 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.checkbox.ReactCheckBoxManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.655 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.picker.ReactDialogPickerManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.659 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.664 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.picker.ReactDropdownPickerManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.666 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollViewManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.668 1507-1528/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.acme.myapp/.MainActivity: +15s858ms
2018-12-04 10:06:20.670 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollContainerViewManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.672 1507-1520/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-12-04 10:06:20.672 1507-1520/? W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
2018-12-04 10:06:20.673 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ReactProgressBarViewManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.675 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.676 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactScrollViewManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.680 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.685 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager$ReactSliderShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.687 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.689 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager$ReactSwitchShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.689 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.toolbar.ReactToolbarManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.705 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.webview.ReactWebViewManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.712 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.swiperefresh.SwipeRefreshLayoutManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.716 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTSurfaceViewManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.716 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTSurfaceViewShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.719 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageViewManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.720 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.723 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.image.ReactImageManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.728 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.modal.ReactModalHostManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.733 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.modal.ModalHostShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.733 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactRawTextManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.734 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactRawTextShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.735 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.742 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.749 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextViewManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.752 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.753 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.761 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.viewpager.ReactViewPagerManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.767 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactVirtualTextViewManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.768 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactVirtualTextShadowNode
2018-12-04 10:06:20.768 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.reactnativenavigation.views.managers.SharedElementTransitionManager
2018-12-04 10:06:20.776 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp D/SayItReactPackage: createNativeModules
2018-12-04 10:06:20.780 1363-1363/? W/SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
2018-12-04 10:06:20.798 2237-2237/? I/zygote: Deoptimizing boolean com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.BitFlags.m(long, long) due to JIT inline cache
2018-12-04 10:06:20.800 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp D/ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge.
2018-12-04 10:06:20.810 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp D/ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge
2018-12-04 10:06:20.819 2237-2237/? W/SearchService: Abort, client detached.
2018-12-04 10:06:20.822 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp D/ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
2018-12-04 10:06:20.823 4603-4682/com.acme.myapp D/ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
2018-12-04 10:06:20.827 4603-4696/com.acme.myapp D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
2018-12-04 10:06:20.828 4603-4696/com.acme.myapp D/ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
2018-12-04 10:06:20.829 4603-4696/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ReactNative: Packager connection already open, nooping.
2018-12-04 10:06:21.115 4603-4696/com.acme.myapp I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.chrome version 58.0.3029.125 (code 303012512)
2018-12-04 10:06:21.776 4603-4696/com.acme.myapp I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 13 ms (timestamps 4161-4174)
2018-12-04 10:06:21.800 4603-4696/com.acme.myapp I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(140)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
2018-12-04 10:06:21.801 4603-4696/com.acme.myapp I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "58.0.3029.125", actual native library version number "58.0.3029.125"
2018-12-04 10:06:21.801 4603-4608/com.acme.myapp I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=23KB
2018-12-04 10:06:21.803 4603-4608/com.acme.myapp I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=30KB, data=23KB
2018-12-04 10:06:21.803 4603-4608/com.acme.myapp I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
2018-12-04 10:06:22.355 4603-4695/com.acme.myapp E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
2018-12-04 10:06:22.355 4603-4695/com.acme.myapp W/InstanceID: Instance ID SDK is deprecated, com.acme.myapp should update to use Firebase Instance ID
2018-12-04 10:06:22.829 1507-1824/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW flg=0x10008000 cmp=com.acme.myapp/com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.NavigationActivity (has extras)} from uid 10082
2018-12-04 10:06:22.862 1354-1354/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8298496
2018-12-04 10:06:23.255 4603-4608/com.acme.myapp I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=60KB, data=43KB
2018-12-04 10:06:23.261 4603-4608/com.acme.myapp I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=60KB, data=43KB
2018-12-04 10:06:23.261 4603-4608/com.acme.myapp I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
2018-12-04 10:06:23.332 1507-1521/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{780009d u0 com.acme.myapp/.MainActivity t8 f}
2018-12-04 10:06:23.857 4603-4608/com.acme.myapp I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=122KB, data=81KB
2018-12-04 10:06:23.858 4603-4608/com.acme.myapp I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=103KB, data=58KB
2018-12-04 10:06:23.919 4603-4608/com.acme.myapp I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=107KB, data=68KB
2018-12-04 10:06:23.920 4603-4608/com.acme.myapp I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=107KB, data=68KB
2018-12-04 10:06:23.921 4603-4608/com.acme.myapp I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
2018-12-04 10:06:24.085 4603-4603/com.acme.myapp W/AHBottomNavigation: The items list should have at least 3 items
2018-12-04 10:06:24.095 4603-4603/com.acme.myapp I/chatty: uid=10082(u0_a82) com.acme.myapp identical 2 lines
2018-12-04 10:06:24.096 4603-4603/com.acme.myapp W/AHBottomNavigation: The items list should have at least 3 items
2018-12-04 10:06:24.145 4603-4603/com.acme.myapp D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
2018-12-04 10:06:24.186 4603-4603/com.acme.myapp I/chatty: uid=10082(u0_a82) com.acme.myapp identical 3 lines
2018-12-04 10:06:24.200 4603-4603/com.acme.myapp D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
2018-12-04 10:06:24.222 4603-4603/com.acme.myapp D/MainApplication: onActivityStarted
2018-12-04 10:06:24.225 4603-4603/com.acme.myapp W/unknown:ReactNative: Packager connection already open, nooping.
2018-12-04 10:06:24.231 4603-4603/com.acme.myapp D/MainApplication: onActivityResumed
2018-12-04 10:06:24.242 4603-4608/com.acme.myapp I/zygote: JIT allocated 71KB for compiled code of void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
2018-12-04 10:06:24.242 4603-4608/com.acme.myapp I/zygote: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
2018-12-04 10:06:24.300 4603-4608/com.acme.myapp I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=208KB, data=139KB
2018-12-04 10:06:24.305 4603-4608/com.acme.myapp I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=166KB, data=91KB
2018-12-04 10:06:24.430 4603-4685/com.acme.myapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3486a40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa34836a0)
2018-12-04 10:06:24.539 1354-1354/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8298496
2018-12-04 10:06:24.734 1507-1528/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.acme.myapp/com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.NavigationActivity: +1s400ms
2018-12-04 10:06:24.810 1354-1354/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8298496
2018-12-04 10:06:24.902 1354-1354/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8298496
2018-12-04 10:06:24.997 4603-4603/com.acme.myapp I/zygote: System.exit called, status: 0
2018-12-04 10:06:24.997 4603-4603/com.acme.myapp I/AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.
2018-12-04 10:06:25.043 1507-1744/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.acme.myapp (pid 4603) has died: fore TOP 
2018-12-04 10:06:25.043 1507-1744/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{19d4434 u0 com.acme.myapp/com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.NavigationActivity t8}: app died, no saved state
2018-12-04 10:06:25.043 1507-1650/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{3053e6e u0 com.acme.myapp/com.acme.myapp.MainActivity}
2018-12-04 10:06:25.046 1507-1565/? W/InputDispatcher: channel '8c246a6 com.acme.myapp/com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.NavigationActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
2018-12-04 10:06:25.046 1507-1565/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '8c246a6 com.acme.myapp/com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.NavigationActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2018-12-04 10:06:25.053 1507-2191/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{8c246a6 u0 com.acme.myapp/com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.NavigationActivity}
2018-12-04 10:06:25.053 1507-2191/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '8c246a6 com.acme.myapp/com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.NavigationActivity (server)'
2018-12-04 10:06:25.067 1507-1528/? W/ActivityManager: setHasOverlayUi called on unknown pid: 4603
2018-12-04 10:06:25.098 1354-1354/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 4096
2018-12-04 10:06:25.103 2200-2339/? I/zygote: Deoptimizing int android.support.v4.a.k.aqf(java.lang.Object) due to JIT inline cache
2018-12-04 10:06:25.180 1354-1354/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 4096
2018-12-04 10:06:25.204 1354-1354/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 4096
2018-12-04 10:06:25.260 1363-1363/? D/SurfaceFlinger: duplicate layer name: changing com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher.NexusLauncherActivity to com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher.NexusLauncherActivity#1
2018-12-04 10:06:25.266 1354-1354/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 4096
2018-12-04 10:06:25.386 1354-1354/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 120 ms
2018-12-04 10:06:25.411 1354-1354/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 4096
2018-12-04 10:06:25.411 2237-2480/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa34863e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa3483b30)
2018-12-04 10:06:25.506 1354-1354/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 4096
2018-12-04 10:06:25.546 2200-2357/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xac9a1aa0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xac9ecf00)
2018-12-04 10:06:25.548 2237-2237/? I/zygote: Deoptimizing void com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.service.worker.a.a.a(com.google.android.apps.gsa.search.core.state.qc) due to JIT inline cache
2018-12-04 10:06:25.565 2237-2237/? W/SessionLifecycleManager: Handover failed. Creating new session controller.
2018-12-04 10:06:25.566 2237-2237/? I/zygote: Deoptimizing com.google.common.collect.dk com.google.common.collect.dk.c(int, java.lang.Object[]) due to JIT inline cache
2018-12-04 10:06:25.572 2237-2237/? I/OptInState: There is a new client and it does not support opt-in. Dropping request.
2018-12-04 10:06:25.605 2237-2237/? I/MicroDetectionWorker: #updateMicroDetector [detectionMode: [mDetectionMode: [1]]]
2018-12-04 10:06:25.605 2237-2237/? I/MicroDetectionWorker: #startMicroDetector [speakerMode: 0]
2018-12-04 10:06:25.606 2237-2237/? I/AudioController: Using mInputStreamFactoryBuilder
2018-12-04 10:06:25.611 2237-2419/? I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Starting detection.
2018-12-04 10:06:25.611 2237-2408/? I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_starting com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.aa.c@68bc2a7
2018-12-04 10:06:25.614 2237-2237/? I/MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
2018-12-04 10:06:25.614 2237-2242/? I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=500KB, data=319KB
2018-12-04 10:06:25.616 2237-2242/? I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=492KB, data=315KB
2018-12-04 10:06:25.616 2237-2242/? I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 2MB
2018-12-04 10:06:25.616 1368-4721/? I/AudioFlinger: AudioFlinger's thread 0xa8d83780 tid=4721 ready to run
2018-12-04 10:06:25.628 2237-2408/? I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_started com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.aa.c@68bc2a7
2018-12-04 10:06:25.628 2237-2408/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-12-04 10:06:25.633 2237-2408/? I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_close com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.aa.c@68bc2a7
2018-12-04 10:06:25.634 2237-2419/? I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Detection finished
2018-12-04 10:06:25.634 2237-2419/? W/ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 211, code: 524300]: Error reading from input stream
2018-12-04 10:06:25.635 2237-2585/? I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Stopping hotword detection.
2018-12-04 10:06:25.636 2237-2419/? W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
    com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.b.g: Error reading from input stream
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.j.a.a(SourceFile:28)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.j.b.run(SourceFile:15)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:14)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ai.run(SourceFile:6)
     Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.f(SourceFile:103)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.au.read(SourceFile:2)
        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ao.run(SourceFile:18)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.an.run(SourceFile:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:14) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ai.run(SourceFile:6) 
2018-12-04 10:06:25.636 2237-2419/? I/AudioController: internalShutdown
2018-12-04 10:06:25.645 2237-2237/? I/MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
2018-12-04 10:06:25.645 2237-2237/? I/MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
2018-12-04 10:06:25.645 2237-2439/? I/DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker cancelled
2018-12-04 10:06:25.646 2237-2237/? I/MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
2018-12-04 10:06:26.061 2200-2357/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43228160/android-multidex-support-library-is-disabled

Comment: @Benjamin thanks, I sorted out the Multidex issue but still get a crash

Comment: please run your application on other emulator. and test it

Comment: @MahdiBashirpour I've tried 2 different emulators, crash happens in all of them.

Comment: @Adamski Have You tried deleting cache/nodemodules/ and re installing node-modules, after which open the project in android studio and go to `File->invalidate cache and restart`

Comment: @NaveedSheriffdeen Thanks -  yes, I have tried that, multiple times!

Comment: Does the app use microphone? If the app was on a physical device does it also crash?

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/q/43164577/2949966 ?

Comment: Can you please share the versions of `react` and `react-native` you are using?

Answer (score 3):

Two issues.

### 1. The microphone

The app is looking for the microphone.

```
2018-12-04 10:06:25.605 2237-2237/? I/MicroDetectionWorker: #updateMicroDetector [detectionMode: [mDetectionMode: [1]]]
2018-12-04 10:06:25.605 2237-2237/? I/MicroDetectionWorker: #startMicroDetector [speakerMode: 0]
2018-12-04 10:06:25.606 2237-2237/? I/AudioController: Using mInputStreamFactoryBuilder
2018-12-04 10:06:25.611 2237-2419/? I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Starting detection.
2018-12-04 10:06:25.611 2237-2408/? I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_starting com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.aa.c@68bc2a7
2018-12-04 10:06:25.614 2237-2237/? I/MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
2018-12-04 10:06:25.614 2237-2242/? I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=500KB, data=319KB
2018-12-04 10:06:25.616 2237-2242/? I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=492KB, data=315KB
2018-12-04 10:06:25.616 2237-2242/? I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 2MB
2018-12-04 10:06:25.616 1368-4721/? I/AudioFlinger: AudioFlinger's thread 0xa8d83780 tid=4721 ready to run
```

The app is attempting to get the input stream from the microphone and fails.

```
2018-12-04 10:06:25.628 2237-2408/? I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_started com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.aa.c@68bc2a7
2018-12-04 10:06:25.628 2237-2408/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
```

It closes the input stream.

```
2018-12-04 10:06:25.633 2237-2408/? I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_close com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.aa.c@68bc2a7
2018-12-04 10:06:25.634 2237-2419/? I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Detection finished
```

But it cannot read from the stream (as there is none).

```
2018-12-04 10:06:25.634 2237-2419/? W/ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 211, code: 524300]: Error reading from input stream
2018-12-04 10:06:25.635 2237-2585/? I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Stopping hotword detection.
2018-12-04 10:06:25.636 2237-2419/? W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.b.g: Error reading from input stream
```

You need error handling for your microphone. Check that there is one and that it's enabled, so the app doesn't crash. Particularly for an emulator, but also so it doesn't crash if you haven't handled your permissions correctly when the app is deployed to a real device. Test it on both the emulator and a real device.

Some more tips from these:

[GsaIOException Buffer overflow, no available space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42428565/3956566)

[Looping Error on Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43164577/3956566)

Ensure  to include `permission.RECORD_AUDIO`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

### 2. [Android Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views #6692](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6692)

Ensure the [google play services versions match](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6692#issuecomment-336636295) throughout all the app dependencies.

> In my case I solved this by using same google play services versions across imported modules.
>   In my case 2 modules were using google play services.
>
> 1. react-native-maps module was using com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:**10.2.4**
> 2. background-location module was using com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:**11.0.2**
>      So, I changed **10.2.4** to **11.0.2**
>      you can find this in build.gradle file under dependencies { }

Ensure you're using [React Native v0.53.0 or newer](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6692#issuecomment-368195546).

Add the following to [your build gradle](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-blur/issues/110#issuecomment-272956182):

```
renderscriptTargetApi 21
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

Comment: Let me know if this solves it. Also check out the remainder of those github threads.

Answer (score 2):

the log-cat starts complaining after `ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge.`

therefore, this might be ProGuard related (in case only release builds are being affected);

found this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15621), which suggests to replace:

```
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.ModuleRegistryHolder { *; }
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl { *; }
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.JavaScriptExecutor { *; }
```

with:

```
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl { *; }
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptExecutor { *; }
```

Comment: @YvetteColomb this can happen, when Java classes are being refactored and the associated ProGuard rules are not being updated accordingly - which leads to rules which then won't exclude the required classes/interfaces/methods from the obfuscation anymore. using the rules from an elder version might have the same effect.